# Query taking a lot of time when subquery with not in clause is not returning any value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure with a `select` query that has a subquery and `not in` clause.

When the subquery is returning some value, then the select query is returning the result within 1 second, but when the subquery is not returning any value, then the query is taking 2 minutes to execute.

I have searched and suggestions are either using the `not exists` clause or using join. But both seems not ideal for my case as I am using the same table. I may be wrong. need your guide on this

This is my query

```sql
select
    -- @vNewParentId,
    -- @pNewEntityId,
    AppEntityAttribute.AppEntityAttributeName,
    AppEntityAttribute.AttributeDataTypeId,
    AppEntityAttribute.IsProductionReady
from 
    AppEntityAttribute
where 
    AppEntityId = 'DAFC0508-A899-408D-8650-543BFA6909B4'
    and AppEntityAttribute.ParentAppEntityAttributeId = 1353321
    and AppEntityAttribute.OrganizationId is null
    and AppEntityAttribute.ProcessflowId is null
    and AppEntityAttribute.NodeId is null
    and AppEntityAttribute.AppEntityAttributeId 
        not in (select AppEntityAttribute.ParentId 
                from AppEntityAttribute
                where AppEntityAttribute.AppEntityId = '79A5E185-6EF1-4BCF-802F-E2BF1962876B'
                  and AppEntityAttribute.OrganizationId is null
                  and AppEntityAttribute.ProcessflowId is null
                  and AppEntityAttribute.NodeId is null)
order by 
    AppEntityAttribute.AppEntityAttributeId
```

Comment: For performance questions please include the execution plan using Paste The Plan

Comment: Just for easy flow, can you post the resulting SQL query too please? You can get it using the `.ToQueryString()` on your LINQ query

Comment: This is the actual SQL query

Comment: > `" ... as I am using the same table."` It may be the same table, but think of it as a **different instance** of the table. It's still a whole separate set of reads/memory access ops. Usually `EXISTS()` is the best option, but occasionally the DB will do a better job finding indexes with a self join.

Comment: I would ensure you have an index on your AppEntityAttribute table based
on the following ( AppEntityID, OrganizationId, ProcessFlowId, NodeId, ParentAppEntityAttributeID )

Comment: We need at the very least an execution plan, which you can share via https://pastetheplan.com. Please also show your table and index definitions.

Answer (score 3):

Try with `NOT EXISTS` :

```
select   
    AppEntityAttributeName,
    AttributeDataTypeId,
    IsProductionReady   
from AppEntityAttribute A
where AppEntityId = 'DAFC0508-A899-408D-8650-543BFA6909B4' 
    and ParentAppEntityAttributeId=1353321
    and OrganizationId  is null 
    and ProcessflowId  is null 
    and NodeId  is null
    and not exists (
        select 1 
        from AppEntityAttribute B
        where B.AppEntityId ='79A5E185-6EF1-4BCF-802F-E2BF1962876B'
            and B.OrganizationId  is null
            and B.ProcessflowId  is null 
            and B.NodeId  is null
            and A.AppEntityAttributeId=B.ParentId
        )
order by AppEntityAttributeId
```

Comment: even not exist is takin 1.5 min.

Comment: @Utpal we need the execution plan - SQL only describes the results you want - it's doesn't say anything about how the engine obtains those results. Your slow query is not down to query structure but missing indexes etc

Comment: 2 min down to 1.5 min is still a 25% improvement. That's a change worth keeping.

Answer (score 1):

The following indexes could make @SomendraKanaujia 's query faster:

```
create index ix1 on AppEntityAttribute (
  AppEntityId, ParentAppEntityAttributeId, OrganizationId,
  ProcessflowId, NodeId, AppEntityAttributeId
);

create index ix2 on AppEntityAttribute (
  AppEntityId, AppEntityAttributeId, 
  OrganizationId, ProcessflowId, NodeId
);
```